# Installing SBT on Ubuntu - Module not found

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

I'm trying to install SBT on Ubuntu 12.04 by using the DEB provided here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Getting-Started/Setup.html .

After running *sbt* however, I get the error:

```
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.0 ...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.0

    ==== local: tried

      /root/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.0/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== sbt-releases-repo: tried

      http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.0/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== sbt-plugins-repo: tried

      http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.0/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== maven-central: tried

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.0/sbt-0.13.0.pom

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.0: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

And inspecting update.log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: not found
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.IvyNode.loadData(IvyNode.java:238)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.VisitNode.loadData(VisitNode.java:292)
...

Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
    at xsbt.boot.Pre$.error(Pre.scala:26)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.xsbt$boot$Update$$lockedApply(Update.scala:105)
```

Any help?

Thank you

Comment: It was just a general problem with the repo, should be working now

Comment: @lpiepiora Indeed! working now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My context was installing apache-spark on 14.04 but I had a similar problem.  Someone else provided an answer in another thread:

```
sudo apt-get -y install ca-cacert
```

After this it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, same problem with 0.13.5, something wrong, maybe SBT removed or moved from repositories. i have in ivy cache 0.13.0 and 0.13.1 version, try to 
extract [archive](https://mega.co.nz/#!qZp2AYaC!haZUyy2PYbCv_cfNm9_Gu9clzv15wce-OB8jzZ2rx3w) into

```
~/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-sbt/sbt/
```

or

```
~/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/
```

hope it helps

Comment: You are not supposed to use minified URLs on SO. Besides, your answer is not quite useful given that this is an issue on typesafe repo servers and you have pointed your minified url to a cloud storage. Replace it with the direct url. See [this Meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64450) about use of URL shorteners on SO.

Comment: link fixed.
yes, my answer not quite useful, but i suggested a temporary solution