# sbt don't work properly - module not found: org.scala-sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

When I run `sbt(0.12.4)` on my PC - `Win8.1 x86` - I get the error messages `module not found: org.scala-sbt`.

> ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
>
> http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.12.4/ivys/ivy.xml

I suspect that the `URL` is wrong.
On my PC browser I can't connect there but connect to "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/simple/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.12.4/ivys/ivy.xml"

The difference is at `/simple/` in the middle of the `URL`.

Maybe there has to be an alias between them, but it doesn't now.

How can I fix this problem?
Or could `typesafe.com` fix it?

Comment: I think it's the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978830/installing-sbt-on-ubuntu-module-not-found - seems there is a porblem with the repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

current news: https://twitter.com/search?q=sbt

```
posted by sbt ‏@scala_sbt  20 min ago
we are having proxy issue right now with ivy-release repo. JFrog is on it to fix this
```